# How can we define differential coefficient of a vector valued function in terms of linear operator?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

As far as I know differential coefficient of a function is constant.Then how is the constant related with linear operator.I feel pretty surprised when I came to know it from one of my friend.But how can a constant be treated as a mapping?I wonder!Please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "co-efficient" is in fact "coefficient".

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to say.

Comment: It is a small orthographic remark: no "-" inside the word coefficient (it is true it is not the first time I see it...).

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Now is it ok?I have just edited my post.

Comment: @copper.hat I was asking how can differential coefficient be a linear map.How can a constant behave like an operator? It surprises me a lot.

Comment: What is a differential coefficient? What constant? You need to provide some context.

Comment: If a function $f : \mathbb R^{n} \longrightarrow \mathbb R^{m}$ is differentiable at a point $c \in \mathbb R^{n}$ then the total derivative of $f$ at $c$ is the differential coefficient of $f$ at $c$.Is it not a constant vector of $\mathbb R^{m}$?